# Where to store project resource files?

Tags: best-practices

You are working on a website for a client. He (the client) sends you a bunch of MS Word documents with text that you have to use in the website.

Where do you store them?

My approach would be to store them on my local server along with the source files for the website - in a folder named "res" (for "resources").

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense. Are the word documents going to be downloaded from links on the site or do they just contain text FOR the site?

Comment: @Piers, No, I'd store the files there for my own convenience only.

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter where you store them, does it? As long as you remember where you put them

Comment: @Piers, For the website itself it might not matter. It matters to me. Being organized helps me be more efficient. I believe that's true for most people.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I don't think this is really a valid question. You're basically asking "where should I store some files so I remember where they are?"

Comment: @Piers, Wouldn't you be interested to find out how different people / organizations organize the files for their projects?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. You're looking for answers like sharepoint or some other document management system?

Comment: @Piers, Sure, a system or just a general approach.

Comment: Yea, this seems like a really trivial question. It doesn't really matter where you put it. I put them in `E:\projects\projectname` at home, but at work they're in `C:\backup\sites\projectname`. A coworker might put them in `My Documents\projectname` or `Desktop\workspace\projectname`. There's no difference.

Comment: @Emanuil: Aside from using a proper project management application, how many different approaches are there to putting a set of documents in a folder? This isn't quite the same as designing a file structure for an application. I just don't think it's worth putting too much thought into. Though if you expanded the question to be "what are some useful project management practices?" that might be a worthwhile question.

Comment: @Lèse majesté, I guess you are right.

Comment: @Emanuil Using any system that allows you to track changes for documentation worthwhile, the rest are dummy details. @Lèse majesté, nice sharp comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is value in storing them in an FTP-accessible directory for their site, calling it whatever... such as "ClientProvided" or "SourceDocuments."

Here is why:

- Client, if they have FTP access, would unquestionably have access to the same docs they provided to you
- Should you ever lose their account, or wish to fire them as a customer, everything is ready for transition to another web professional

While some people might have the opinion that if you don't do business with them you won't care or need to give them such source material, I'm of the belief that it's easier to just hand everything over (within your terms and conditions). What you don't want is future repeated calls for a trickling out of more files, more history/info, and also any suggestion by the client or another firm that you are uncooperative.

Like Kris suggested, JIRA and/or SVN could also be good places to put that data, but you might not want to hand over the contents of those, perhaps more internal and sensitive, forms of data.

Answer (score 1):

We use [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) as an issue tracker. In the scenario you describe I'd open an issue on the update being requested and attach the Word document to the issue.